# Apache Camel JSON Marshalling to POJO Java Bean

Tags: json, apache-camel, marshalling, unmarshalling

I think I have a simple question, but can't seem to figure it out.

I'm invoking a POJO with a class created from unmarshalling JSON as the parameter for the method. The question is, how do I marshal the return from the method back to JSON?

My route is below;

```
from("direct:start")
 .choice()
  .when(header("methodname").isEqualTo("listCases"))
   .unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, UserDetails.class)
   .to("bean:com.xxx.BeanA")
  .when(header("methodName").isEqualTo("listPersons"))
   .unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, CaseDetails.class)
   .to("bean:com.xxx.BeanB");
```

...and I'm invoking the route by the below;

```
ProducerTemplate template = camelContext.createProducerTemplate();
template.setDefaultEndpoint(camelContext.getEndpoint("direct:start"));
InvocationResult result = (InvocationResult)template.requestBodyAndHeader(payload, "methodName", methodName);
```

Payload is JSON, and the methodName is either listCases or listPersons in this example.

My InvocationResult class is generic and contains a String returnCode attribute as well as an object reference to the object I would like to be converted to JSON. This object will be different depending on whether listCases or listPersons is executed.

Thanks,

Bic

Comment: You're already using `unmarshall()` with Jackson. Do you have any issue with using `marshall()` similarly? As long as the response can be marshalled by Jackson, it should be straightforward enough?

Comment: The unmarshalling is working fine - so in the example above, I see my payload JSON is being converted to a UserDetails class.

The problem is that I don't know how to marshal one of the fields in the InvocationResult class - the Object which needs to be converted to JSON.

Comment: So given that I can unmarshall JSON to a POJO to pass into a bean, I guess my question boils down to how I do the reverse - to marshal the object returned by the bean back to JSON?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My impression is that your actual issue isn't about marshalling (which should be entirely straightforward), but about processing a response after having routed the message using `choice()`. You need to close the `choice()` block using `end()` (assuming the result of each branch will be processed in the same way), then make sure the response gets written to the `out` message body in the last step of the route.

Anyway, here is an example I've just tested:

```
public class JacksonTestRoute extends RouteBuilder {
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("jetty:http://localhost:8181/foo").to("direct:foo");

        from("direct:foo")
        .unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, Foo.class)
        .choice()
            .when().simple("${body.foo} == 'toto'")
                .log("sending to beanA")
                .to("bean:beanA")
            .otherwise()
                .log("sending to beanB")
                .to("bean:beanB")
        // close the choice() block :
        .end()
        // per the javadoc for marshall(), "the output will be added to the out body" :
        .marshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson);
    }
}

public class Foo {
    private String foo; // Constructor and accessor omitted for brevity
}

public class Bar1 {
    private String bar1; // Constructor and accessor omitted for brevity
}

public class Bar2 {
    private String bar2; // Constructor and accessor omitted for brevity
}

public class BeanA {
    public Bar1 doSomething(final Foo arg) {
        return new Bar1(arg.getFoo() + "A");
    }
}

public class BeanB {
    public Bar2 doSomething(final Foo arg) {
        return new Bar2(arg.getFoo() + "B");
    }
}
```

POSTing `{"foo":"toto"}` returns `{"bar1":"totoA"}` (and logs `sending to beanA`).

POSTing `{"foo":"titi"}` returns `{"bar2":"titiB"}` (and logs `sending to beanB`).

Answer (score 2):

It is as simple as this `.marshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson)` (this is what you want)

Comment: I tried that, but it doesn't take effect;

    `from("direct:start")
    .choice()
 .when(header("methodname").isEqualTo("listCases"))
  .unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, UserDetails.class)
  .to("bean:com.xxx.BeanA")
 .when(header("methodName").isEqualTo("listPersons"))
  .unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, CaseDetails.class)
  .to("bean:com.xxx.BeanB")
.marshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson);`


My InvocationResult object is returned as is, neither it nor any of its attributes are converted to JSON format - what am I missing?